# Flutter App can't launching in iPhone without connecting to the computer?

Tags: flutter

I can build & launching app well in my iPhone when my phone is connecting to the macbook , and launching by the command line `flutter run`.

But when i disconnect my iPhone from the macbook . and I want to launch the app from the iPhone's desktop. the app seems can't launch , and will exit very soon.

Is there any way to launch flutter app from the iPhone's desktop?

Comment: didn't Xcodes  Network debugging  work?

Comment: I didn't using the Xcode yet , I just using the Android studio to build and launch

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is happen because you are building iOS app in `debug` mode, run app in `profile` or `release` mode and it will fix.

Comment: Thanks , But if the mode is wrong , why I can run this app when launch by Android studio?

Comment: this is related to apple policy, more information (https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/ios/ios-debugging#launching-debug-flutter-without-a-host-computer)

Comment: it is not wrong mode, debug mode in ios device is just for developing, if you are interested to use it after a while you should build it in other mode.

Comment: some document say that :when the flutter build in debug mode , the app will build in JIT mode . and the JIT mode will be restricted in iOS14 and later. so we need to build in non-debug mode

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the  @eamirho3ein's answer: change the debug to release fix the problem.
In fact, there is one thing to be metioned: the default config in xcode for command-line build is release already, but if you change this mode won't help. the mode needed to be change is the flutter run mode.
there are many ways to do this.